# Copy file from FTP to ADLS using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-lake

I am trying to pull all archives from a folder in FTP to Azure Data Lake Store using Powershell. I can only find [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datalakestore/move-azurermdatalakestoreitem?view=azurermps-6.2.0) on moving files from or within ADLS, but not from a source outside of ADLS.

I am familiar with Copy-Item, but I don't know how to access ADLS (and input credentials) under the Destination.

```
Copy-Item -Path __ -Destination ___ -Force
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you need to use Import-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem

```
Import-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName ___ -Path ____ -Destination ___
```

This allows you to set the FTP filepath under -Path.